# Can't open my Blob in chrome

Tags: angularjs

i have a little problem, i can t open my blob PDF on google Chrome but on firefox it s work

what s wrong with this simply code

```
//create blob
           var blob = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});

           //put name of blob
           var fileOfBlob = new File([blob], $rootScope.JourSelect+'.pdf');

           //create a url 
           var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileOfBlob);

           //display on another window
           window.open(fileURL);
```

i have something like this on chrome

```
    %PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
/TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> 
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 687>>
stream
¡Ï+ëdtüG>KTx´D‰ëE-®Š:øÙ£Þ/íÔÑüÀ3Vƒ­åmzûÙrEë<Å-Å~õÊ2RÏ=ÔÈšaç‰®j»ýqE©{€cSú¡¹S:9RXC q*^w2  E»+`~ÉvÝýwkS§?l¢#çöð«çPÂK.
YÓCR‰˜£…ôÏM°xÑçõ©z+®¢áüØêÂ[ „
-áûþr%²Ü¯6ß8VÅ^jªDA”­öIó¦ì üqœæ6é½òØX
ŽiÙ,hLkv†½uVöüï.h8Rf3cIú±¢õF(½ªêæp´¸·åYÇíÎÊ?xŠä4sð¾]ÆÝ÷µ ›å+DøC›‚6C¾7K¥8Ü‡¹çGÈ`¤ŸçÚ/LO+çôsLÕ    Tß¡‰Ô•‰­Äµ!ôÐç{ê/ºf;Á=¢V€}…=Á£+‰}¨Q„.?øÁ†Ÿúòßê¨Ò€/!Û[Âò#¼«þÏþA?�Uc™–HÄ,‚m¨œ¸„]7P€¿V 9ËŸª*}{1+ŒÛLÝ§ø›‘öw¬PêqÙsé—.ß÷D7ª3Sæºf¶"ºåð~E‹|Ä{mÏ¯aâ´•0|Cw™U};ÊÌ4ÝùfÚE¨ïåsWÒPL6ŸGx™§7þEU\ž7võŸÜHªŽ;>óaPÂs¡ÞÙ˜xüÅÎIhÖDäŒ·8ó�Äò‚øèF¬BU×Ìt¤³æNµµe÷)LÖ.CõåvÒ4–Sb:wx­lÜ–´ã`    wÇ"c‰>O™Ž-óéúë­AIM¹
```

...

thanks for your help :D

Comment: What is the data source for `data.data`? If it is [DOMstring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), the [Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) will corrupt the data with [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding.

Comment: it s a PDF in base64 like this :JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL01lZGlhQm94IFswIDAgNTk1LjI4MCA4NDEuODkwXQovVHJpbUJveCBbMC4wMDAgMC4wMDAgNTk1LjI4MCA4NDEuODkwXQovUmVzb3VyY2VzIDIgMCBSCi9Hcm91.....